# How to refresh the browser on macOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser, macos-sierra

This seems so basic, but I found no answer. I'm using the MacBook Pro with the touch bar. Crtl + F5 / F5 doesn't work somehow, which is the case for windows computers.

Comment: In mac most CTRL+xxx shortcuts are used with the command key. Tried CMD+F5?

Comment: fn+f5 should work too

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Refresh:** <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (same as <kbd>F5</kbd> on Windows/Linux)

**Refresh cleaning cache:** <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (same as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> on Windows/Linux)

Comment: I moved the accepted answer to this since it is the most straightforward and compact one to my question.

Answer (score 35):

Regular shortcut is  <kbd>Cmd</kbd> - <kbd>Shift</kbd> -<kbd>R</kbd>.

Workaround for <kbd>F5</kbd> adapted from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/If0TdQ2m6hU/ZSrbu8BCDpwJ:

1. Go to "System Preferences" -> "Keyboard" -> "Shortcuts" -> "App Shortcuts"
2. Hit the little "+" button under the main white area
3. In the little pup-up window select "Google Chrome" as the Application
4. Type in "Reload This Page" in the "Menu Title" field exactly as it appears in the Chrome's View menu (no quotes of course)
5. Click inside the "Keyboard Shortcut" field and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> key (or any desired combination)
6. Finish with "Add". Shortcut should work directly.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure this one out for a while.

Comment: Unfortunately when you assign "F5" to "Reload This Page", the "Cmd+R" stops to work -.-

Answer (score 20):

Macs show you their keyboard shortcuts right in the menus. If you look on Safari's `View` menu and see the `Reload Page` command, you'll see it's shortcut is Cmd-R.

Historically, Mac keyboard shortcuts rarely use function keys (F1-F15), because Mac designers and users have tended to favor more compact keyboard layouts that don't have room for the F key row, or nowadays, because that row is primarily used for brightness and volume keys.

Comment: Cmd+R, sweet! I feel a bit ashamed that I didn't look int the menu bar, I thought this was basic and should work on whichever platform. Is there also an equivalent to the windows CTRL-F5? This one isn't listed.

Answer (score 0):

Spiff answered first, and is correct: it's Cmd-R on the Mac.  However, I'm used to F5 in Windows (used in MANY apps, not just browsers), so consider using the Mac's Keyboard preference pane to map F5 to the Reload Page function.  Or use one of the many other shortcut-key tools.

Comment: Actually I started using "ctrl + R" on windows. It's somehow easier accessible without looking at the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, you can use System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts then add your browser with [+] and then set `F5` as a hotkey for the text in the menu you want to trigger.

I've added `^T` for New Tab and `^W` for Close Tab because I'm flipping back and forth between Mac, Windows, and Linux, and changing my mental keyboard mappings on the fly is error-prone and frustrating.

I do wish OSX supported proper focus-follows-mouse (sloppy focus)